# How to display ELM code snippets in a WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress, elm

I'm looking for a WordPress Plugin, or any other way to display ELM code in my blog. I tried to use Crayon, but since it has no special support for elm, the code is colored wrong.

How can I do so?

Comment: I've [opened a pull request](https://github.com/aramk/crayon-syntax-highlighter/pull/400) to add Elm support to Crayon. If you'd like it now, you can use my fork of the plugin, or simply copy its `langs/elm` folder into your existing plugin install.

Comment: Cool, I opened an issue few days ago and considered doing so myself. Ill review you code :)

Comment: Does crayon support Haskell? The syntax is close enough that you could probably get nice highlighting.

Comment: Interesting point, but the problem is solved, since @RyanPlant developed the solution

Answer (score 2):

This https://runelm.io/new provides a way to embed runnable snippets of Elm code on an Elm website. I don't know how easy to do this is because I haven't tested it but the example they give looks promising.

Comment: It isn't quite the solution since it is not wordpressable, but good to know it exists